# Multiple problems with horizontal launch and cryo storage for Stratolaunch?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, air-launch, stratolaunch

The Stratolaunch system claims to be a way to revolutionize launching into LEO. The many problems associate with stress loads for horizontal assembly and the need to carry a rocket to launch altitude with fuel loaded seem to be rather large hurdles.

What techniques are being employed for plane assisted high altitude launches?

Comment: Are you looking for info on the Startolaunch system in particular or Air-Launch in general?

Comment: @Jack Stratolaunch, because of the claim to revolutionize launch systems. They are currently testing rockets that are already air launched, so I'm not seeing how it is revoutionary, other than being really BIG and cool.

Comment: Agreed - since they're currently planning to use the Pegasus XL which has been flying for almost 3 decades, it'd be hard to call it 'revolutionary'. If they can get it to work with a cryo-liquid upper stage then maybe, but I can't find any info on the current development progress. Either way, who doesn't love a massive plane?